# React-rating-rating-stars-component value dose not change

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-rating-starts-component and I've used it multiple time in cards using .map and it work fine. However, when I added it to one page I gave it initial value of 0 and it dose not chnage from that value I updated it value in componentdidmount() using the backend and in console its giving me 5 but it is showing 0

The function that get the stars and view them

```
function getstars(props){
  return(
    <ReactStars 
    value={props.Rating}
    count={5}
    size={25}
    edit={false}
    isHalf={false}
    activeColor="#ffea00"
/> 
  )
}
```

SetState from componentdidmoount

```
this.setState({
        info: resp.data.PlaceInformation,
          id: resp.data.PlaceInformation._id,
          Name: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Name,
          Description: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Description,
          Phone: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Phone,
          Website: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Website,
          Instagram: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Instgram,
          Twitter: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Twitter,
          Rating: resp.data.PlaceInformation.Rating,
          PRating: resp.data.PlaceInformation.PRating,
          OpenTime: resp.data.PlaceInformation.OpenTime,
          CloseTime: resp.data.PlaceInformation.CloseTime,
          Image: resp.data.PlaceInformation.icon,
          Photos: resp.data.PlaceInformation.photos,
          GoogleMap: resp.data.PlaceLocation.GoogleMap,
          City: resp.data.PlaceLocation.City,
          Street: resp.data.PlaceLocation.Street,
          ZibCode: resp.data.PlaceLocation.ZibCode,
          Reviews: resp.data.PlaceReviews,
  })
```

In react render

```
<div>{getstars(this.state.Rating)}</div>
```

The initialed value of Rating is "0" and it dose not change in starts but changes in console .
When I change the initialed value of rating it changes.
Thank You for helping me out and taking it into your consideration :)

Comment: Can you create a sandbox like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-mountain-w3ngk?file=/src/App.js:1363-1376) to reproduce your issue? By the way, it looks like you forgot to implement the `onChange` prop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check your arguments.
In the function `getStars` you are passing the `this.state.Rating` object and not the whole state, so when you are using it inside, I guess you should be directly using it, instead of getting it from props.

```
<div>{getstars(this.state.Rating)}</div> 
//You passed the whole Rating object here
```

The code should be

```
function getstars(Rating){
  return(
    <ReactStars 
    value={Rating}
    count={5}
    size={25}
    edit={false}
    isHalf={false}
    activeColor="#ffea00"
/> 
  )
}
```

Alternatively, you can change the way you are passing and pass it using object literal so that you can fetch `Rating` inside the `props` argument.

```
<div>{getstars({Rating: this.state.Rating } )}</div> 
//Here you wrap the Rating with object literal 
//so that in the function you can fetch it from props argument
```

Then there is no need to change your `getStars` function.

Comment: can you check if your resp.data.PlaceInformation.Rating has data. if you could give me a codesandbox , it will be really helpful for me to assist you debug. you can try put console.log and see the argument in `function getstars` also.